# Dynamic data structures in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, dynamic-data, dynamic

I have data in a database, and my code is accessing it using LINQ to Entities.

I am writing some software where I need to be able to create a dynamic script. Clients may write the scripts, but it is more likely that they will just modify them. The script will specify stuff like this,

```
Dataset data = GetDataset("table_name", "field = '1'");

if (data.Read())
{
    string field = data["field"];
    while (cway.Read())
    {
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

So that script above is going to read data from the database table called 'table_name' in the database into a list of some kind based on the filter I have specified 'field='1''. It is going to be reading particular fields and performing normal comparisons and calculations.

The most important thing is that this has to be dynamic. I can specify any table in our database, any filter and I then must be able to access any field.

I am using a script engine that means the script I am writing has to be written in C#. Datasets are outdated and I would rather keep away from them.

Just to re-iterate I am not really wanting to keep with the above format, and I can define any method I want to behind the scenes for my C# script to call. The above could end up like this for instance,

```
var data = GetData("table_name", "field = '1'");

while (data.ReadNext())
{
    var value = data.DynamicField;
}
```

Can I use reflection for instance, but perhaps that would be too slow? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read dynamically a DataReader context, it's a pretty easy step:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
SqlDataReader dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
   while (dataReader.Read())
   {
   string[] fields = new string[datareader.FieldCount];
   for (int i =0; i < datareader.FieldCount; ++i)
   {
      fields[i] = dataReader[i].ToString() ;
   }
   al.Add(fields);
   }
```

}
This will return an array list composed by a dynamic object based on the number of field the reader has.

Comment: Thanks, but you are pulling out all data into the array list with no regard for the field names. I am looking for a modern way to code this. Not using datasets or arraylists, using LINQ to Entities if possible. I am looking for a way to dynamically hold a collection of records and access particular fields in those records inside the script.